# Simple Splash Screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to follow a simple splash screen example I found.  But I cannot get it to even compile.

First this is the source of the example [here](http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html).

I am trying to put in into a form that would work for my program.

I created a class in Eclipse for this splash screen

```
com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.ePNSplash
```

Here is my current main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.splash"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello World, splash"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the class itself

```
package com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView; 

public class ePNSplash extends Activity {
    private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
    //time in milliseconds
    private static final long SPLASHTIME = 3000;
    
    private ImageView splash;
    
    //handler for splash screen
    private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
         /* (non-Javadoc)
          * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
          */
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              switch (msg.what) {
              case STOPSPLASH:
                   //remove SplashScreen from view
                  splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   break;
              }
              super.handleMessage(msg);
         }
    };
    
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
              splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
              Message msg = new Message();
              msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
              splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
   } 
}
```

XML error:

> no resource found that matches the given name (at src with value
> '@drawable/com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.splash')

I have tried every way I can think to modify the `android:src` but it will not work.

The class is in error because it cannot resolve `r_id.splashscreen` in the find by id line.

This is all greek to me, how should this trivial xml and/or java file be modified to make this work?

Comment: Did you try `@drawable/com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.ePNSplash`?

Comment: Same result, except that it lists "@drawable/com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.ePNSplash"

Answer (score 8):

In `android:src="@drawable/com.ePN.ePNMobileAndroid.splash"` what are you trying to display in this ImageView?  This needs to be a reference to something in your **res/drawable** directory.  So for example if you had a file in res/drawable named **my_splash_image.png** then the XML attribute would be `android:src="@drawable/my_splash_image"`.  Whatever you're trying to do with that package naming inside that attribute isn't going to work.

Looking at the example you are working from, it looks like they had a res/drawable/splash.png file that they were using, that they didn't include in their forum post.

Comment: Yes, it turns out I did not have the image as you  have pointed out.  TY